# Extract paragraphs and CFI from EPUB

Tags: python, epub

I'm trying to extract all paragraphs from and EPUB with associated CFIs. I tried computing the CFI myself but the documentation is really hard to follow and implement. I'm primarily looking for a python solution, but I can work with anything.

To be precise: I want to compute the CFI for every `<p>` inside every chapter.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I've tried all major epub libraries with no luck: epublib (python), epub.js, readium etc.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out how to do this? I am interested in solving the same problem.

Comment: Not yet. I have some code that mostly works, but I added lots of exceptions and still find issues with new epubs

Answer (score 0):

```
async function createCfisForEpubHtmlParagraphs(epub_path){
  const data = await fs.readFile(epub_path, "utf8");
  const dom = new JSDOM(data);
  
  let nodeRange = dom.window.document.createRange();

  const cfiRanges = [...Array(dom.window.document.getElementsByTagName('p').length).keys()].map((paragraphIndx => {
    const pNode = dom.window.document.getElementsByTagName('p').item(paragraphIndx);
    
    nodeRange.setStart(pNode.firstChild, 0);
    try{
      nodeRange.setEnd(pNode.firstChild, pNode.firstChild.textContent.length);
    }
    catch(e){
      nodeRange.setEnd(pNode.firstChild, 1);
    }
    
    let cfirange = new EpubCFI(nodeRange, '/6/4').toString();
    return {cfirange: cfirange, p_number:paragraphIndx}
  })
  return cfiRanges;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I appreciate the help. I'll give it a try this week, but I think it will have the same issue as my own code. At the first glance, you are assuming a fixed depth for the epub structure. However, I found lots of epubs that add some non-visible elements and randomly increase the depth. You can try almost any epib from project Gutenberg.